# Online Video Error

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I've upload a couple of videos so that it can be viewed online and I'm currently testing them on my website. Sometimes the video plays and sometime it stops playing and I get the following error:
GET  net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Thanks in advance for your assistance.